# Retornando um array de uma função no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query, funções

Eu estou com uma dúvida aqui que preciso solucionar com uma função no banco de dados postgreSQL.

O problema é o seguinte, eu preciso cruzar uma tabela que se chama *estoque_alt* com uma view chamada de *estoque*. Nessa tabela *estoque_alt* ficam apenas os códigos dos registro que tiveram seu estoque atualizado, os campos são id_geral, comando e dt_atz, já a view *estoque* trás todos os registros da tabela estoque conforme sua filial e etc.

Se eu cruzar as duas, comparando os id_geral de ambas a query demora consideravelmente para trazer os registros, mesmo que sejam poucos (leva em torno de uns 50 segundo para trazer 4 registros).

Então eu preciso primeiro selecionar todos os registros da tabela *estoque_alt* e após isso verificar todos os registros na view *estoque* que estejam de acordo com o que resultou na primeira consulta. Algo como o que está abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM estoque WHERE id_geral IN (001,002,003)
```

Isso deve ser retornado junto com o valor do campo comando da tabela *estoque_alt*.

Existe uma forma de eu fazer isso dentro de uma função do banco de dados para que seja possível eu apenas chamar a função e ele me retornar todas essas informações?

Comment: E o array entra onde nesse problema ou solução?

Comment: É que eu preciso fazer duas queries dentro da função e percorrer o resultado da primeira na segunda... para eu saber quais registro da id_geral eu vou colocar na cláusula IN()  da segunda query.

Comment: Pode colocar o código da função?

Comment: Aí está, como não trabalho diretamente com banco não tenho ideia de como montar essa função... Por isso precisava de uma ajuda de como chegar nessa solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você precisa, mas veja abaixo

Aqui criei uma função que retorna os ID de usuarios maior igual a 1 e menor igual a 30

```
CREATE FUNCTION ids_para_where(@id int)
returns table
as
RETURN (SELECT USU_CODIGO
        FROM  USUARIO
        WHERE USU_CODIGO >= 1 AND USU_CODIGO <=30)
```

abaixo faço o select passando no where o resultado da função

```
SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USU_CODIGO IN (SELECT * FROM ids_para_where (1))
```

veja se isso ajuda

Comment: Solucionou o problema, embora a performance ainda esteja questionável... Mas obrigado pelo auxílio!